# php. Как добавить или удалить символы BOM в начале файла

Tags: php, linux

На сервере установлен centos. Через php файл принимаю csv файлы в utf8 кодировке. Если файл в формате utf8-bom, то все работает ок, если же файл в формате просто utf8 без BOM, то мне не удается считать нормально первый элемент заголовка в CSV файле. Файл загружают пользователи и иногда грузят в utf8 просто, иногда в utf8-BOM. Как в php определить, есть ли символы BOM в начале файла и добавить их, если их нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function remove_utf8_bom($text)
{
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну вниз тогда тоже напишите, что только мне? У меня код не требующий пояснений, а рассказывать людям про то, как работает `pack()` и так далее в рамках этого вопроса нет смысла.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = file_get_contents($uploadfile); // $uploadfile - файл переданный через форму на сайте
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
$BOMCHARS = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
if (0 === strncmp($str, $bom, 3)) {
    //echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8 BOM\n";
    //$str = substr($str, 3); // удаление BOM символов в начале файла.
}
else {
    //echo "BOM does not detected - file is UTF-8\n";
    $str = substr_replace($str, $BOMCHARS, 0, 0);
    file_put_contents($uploadfile, $str); // добавление BOM символов в начало файла.
}
```